# Bitwise Operators from ANSI C K&R

Tags: c

In the page 49 of ANSI C by K&R, the authors says that

> `x = x & ~077`
>   sets the last six bit of `x` to zero. Note that `x & ~077` is independent of word length, and it thus preferable to, for example, `x & 0177700`, which assumes that `x` is a 16 bit quantity.

My question is that why the authors consider the x as 16 bit quantity whereas 0177700 is total of 21 bit? should I ignore the first 0 bit when I count the number of bits from 0177700 (ex: 177700)?

Second of all, is the passage saying that using `~077` is more flexible and useful as it can be applied to any `x` values regardless of its size?

Comment: What type is `x`?

Comment: It is saying that using `0177700` makes the assumption that `x` is 16 bits for it to work, whereas `~077` makes no such assumption.  what would happen with `x = x & 0177700` such that `x` were a 32 bit value?

Comment: `0177700` is binary `1111 1111 1100 0000` - i.e. 16 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The leading `0` in octal literals should not be counted, that's just part of the syntax (not that leading zeroes should count, anyway). `0177700` fits in 16 bits since the most significant octal digit is 1. The value is equal to `0xffc0` which is obviously a 16-bit value.

Yes, using an inverted small literal is slightly more flexible since it encodes less information in the literal.

If you want to clear the lowest bit of an integer, doing

```
x &= ~1u;
```

is more flexible since it will work just the same on platforms with 16-bit integers as on 32-bit platforms, but the more explicit

```
x &= 0xfffeu;
```

will not, since it assumes 16 bits and doesn't provide masking bits for bits 16 through 31, should they be present.

Answer (score 5):

It should be easier to visualize if you convert those octals to binary:

```
077:
0011 1111

~077:
1100 0000

0177700:
1111 1111 1100 0000
```

> why the authors consider the x as 16 bit quantity whereas 0177700 is total of 21 bit?

It is not, as you can see above. 0177700 takes 16 bit in fact.

> is the passage saying that using ~077 is more flexible and useful as it can be applied to any x values regardless of its size?

Exactly. If you consider a byte being the smallest possible unit for handling, the bitwise NOT of 077 (`~077`) represents the smallest possible number containing the last six bits set to 0 and the remaining ones (only two) set to one. If you want to set the last 6 bit of an arbitrary word to 0, you need to AND it with something that fits this description (last 6 set to 0 and others to 1). And `~077` is the most adequate fit being the smallest possible containing these requirements.

If you would AND it to 0177700, you are assuming the word is at least 16 bit long.

This is heavily based on the fact that you can't AND two different sizes. With `~077`, and considering this:

```
x & ~077
```

If `x` is of a type bigger than 077, let's say 16bit, 077 will first be "promoted" by being padded with zeros:

```
0000 0000 0011 1111
```

And then inverted generating the desired

```
1111 1111 1100 0000
```

Had you used 0177700, if `x` was 8bit long, you have a problem. That's why they say you'd be assuming `x` is 16bit long. In other words, `~077` is the smallest and most adequate fit for that job of setting the last six bits to 0.

Similarly, using 0300 (which is `~077` resolved) you would be assuming that `x` is 8bit. Losing the flexibility that type promotion provides in `~077`.

Comment: "Had you used 0177700, if x was 8bit long, you have a problem." - Why can't x be promoted to 16bit by zero padding thus avoiding the problem? My guess is that the trouble arises if say you try to AND a 32bit x with a 16bit 0177700 since then 0177700 has to be extended to 32bits, but by 1's padding - not 0's, however that would change the value of the constant which is illegal, thus either the expression woulnd't compile or it would lose data. Am I correct?

Comment: @ahra you are correct. The problem arrises with a 32bit. 0177700 will be padded with zeroes, effectively defeating the purpose as it will set the first 16 bits to zero as well as the last 6. I encourage you to edit my answer to correct that, if you will.